# How do I force google action to switch the language during conversation?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a bot for the google assistant using the [action-on-google sdk](https://developers.google.com/actions/overview) and dialogflow in a [webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook).

During the conversation, I need to give to the user the option to switch the language, as the implemented language detection doesn't work every time.

Exemple, in the middle of the conversation:

- Assistant: "do you want to ask your question in English or in
  French?"
- User: "in French"
- Assistant: "D'accord, j'écoute votre question..."

All I have found is that I can get the language of the request with `agent.locale`, but I haven't found any way to set it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The platform doesn't support swapping languages dynamically.

Comment: Is this answer still the same in 2021?

Comment: Yes, there's been no change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any SDK to call dialogflow then you can change language code based on some logic or some utterance (maybe identify the language and pass the language code accordingly).

For python SDK you can use below code and change the `language_code` accordingly.

```
text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code="en")
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems that changing the language on Dialogflow just helps for the intent detection and has no impact on Google action...